# How to add /bigobj switch to clang with ms code gen?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang

I have tried adding /bigobj for the Command Line -> Additional Options but the output is:

clang.exe : error : no such file or directory: '/bigobj'

which is odd since this version of clang with MS code gen (May 2016) is supposed to support this option and using it with the normal MS front end works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, it's because you should use "-" rather than "/", so "-bigobj" instead of "/bigobj"